# ASP.NET Core NullReferenceException After form is posted

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am getting NullReferenceException when I post the form back to the server. I am using ADO.NET with ASP.NET Core 3

Below is the Model for Campgrounds:

```
public class Campground
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    [Display(Name = "Campground Name")]
    public string CampgroundName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int State { get; set; }
    public List<State> States { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Peak { get; set; }
    public List<Month> Months { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Overview { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Season Date From")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/YYYY}")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? SeasonDateFrom { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Season Date To")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/YYYY}")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime SeasonDateTo { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Natural Features")]
    public string NaturalFeatures { get; set; }

    public string Recreation { get; set; }

    public string Facilities { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Campground Photo")]
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

I also have created a ViewModel and I called it CampgroundDetails:

```
 public class CampgroundDetails : Campground
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Campground Image")]
    public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried different approaches but I am not able to move on because of this error. Your help is much appreciated.

Here is the HttpGet of Create Method:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        CampgroundDetails campgroundDetails = new CampgroundDetails();
        List<State> states = new List<State>();
        List<Month> months = new List<Month>();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.DBCS))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_GetStates_Months", connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    ada.Fill(ds);

                    DataTable statesDataTable = ds.Tables[0];
                    foreach(DataRow row in statesDataTable.Rows)
                    {
                        states.Add(new State()
                        {
                            ID = Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"]),
                            StateName = row["StateName"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                    campgroundDetails.States = states;

                    DataTable monthsDataTable = ds.Tables[1];
                    foreach(DataRow row in monthsDataTable.Rows)
                    {
                        months.Add(new Month()
                        {
                            ID = Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"]),
                            MonthName = row["Month"].ToString()
                        }); ;
                    }
                    campgroundDetails.Months = months;
                }
            }
        }
        return View(campgroundDetails);
    }
```

Here is the HttpPost of Create Method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(CampgroundDetails campgroundDetails)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string filePath = UploadFile(campgroundDetails);

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.DBCS))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertNewCampground", connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CampgroundName", campgroundDetails.CampgroundName);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", campgroundDetails.State);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Peak", campgroundDetails.Peak);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeasonDateFrom", campgroundDetails.SeasonDateFrom);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeasonDateTo", campgroundDetails.SeasonDateTo);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NaturalFeatures", campgroundDetails.NaturalFeatures ?? "");
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Recreation", campgroundDetails.Recreation ?? "");
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Facilities", campgroundDetails.Facilities ?? "");
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImagePath", filePath);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Overview", campgroundDetails.Overview);

                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Here is the error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Please post the actual exception. Without it all we are looking at is some class definitions. Also, please post the controller method that the form POST is being sent to.

Comment: Show your controller and how you are making the request

Comment: it seems that your problem is SeasonDateFrom where you make it required and nullable.

Comment: I have added all details

Comment: Your error shows that it tried to select a state on the states view model but there is nothing to select. Something is null. Are you sure when you did a get GET that your model was populated correctly?

Comment: Yes, the states get populated @LukePerrin

Comment: When I traced my code, after postback my form is never valid

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my issue, it is because I made the file upload mandatory